# Video-conference streaming in ASP, what are my options?

Tags: asp.net, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, video-conferencing

I have searched the Internet and found out some information about video-conference streaming, and still, I feel like I don't get the hang of it. I know there are different meeting services available out here, and I wonder if it is possible to integrate/embed one of them in an ASP written website.

1. [Videoconference Streaming Solutions Cookbook](http://www.radvision.com/NR/rdonlyres/DC86B46D-9CAB-457D-92FB-5D1A330AF6BE/0/RADVISIONVideoconferenceStreamingSolutionsCookbook.pdf)
2. [i-meet.com](https://i-meet.com/pages/default/default.aspx)
3. [iMEET - Your own personal meeting room is waiting](https://www.imeet.com/?cid=IM:GS:GBBRAND:T:10-28&gclid=COKhho6X86gCFQzNKgod3ya6Sw)
4. [SO Search Results: Questions Containing 'video streaming asp'](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=video%20streaming%20ASP)

The customer asks for Webcam videoconference streaming feature over his website that is actually written in ASP.

So the questions are:

1. How to build this video-conference streaming feature to work with and ASP written Website?
2. Is it doable to somehow embed the video streaming capability of such iMeet sites into this ASP written Website?
3. Is it doable to use some .NET components for streaming to use within this ASP website?
4. Any question suggestions that might help as well? =)

Thanks for your kind help! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found my answer using `Silverlight 4` and the `CaptureSource` class as described in the following links.

1. [CaptureSource Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.capturesource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx);
2. [Capturing the Webcam in Silverlight 4](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Capturing-the-Webcam-in-Silverlight-4.aspx).

As for streaming the content, I figured out that I would need a server-side service which broadcasts a received content from another source, let's say another Webcam or the-like. Then, the source being captured is available for broadcast.

To receive the content that is streamed from the streaming server, one needs to subscribe at a specific IP or URL and port using the class like "SingleSourceMultipleTarget" (I ain't exactly sure about the class name here, I'll edit when I find the exact class name that I mean).

On the server-side, I would suggest to use the IIS 7 and over SmoothStreaming capability discussed here: [Getting Started with IIS Live Smooth Streaming](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/620/getting-started-with-iis-live-smooth-streaming/). I shall add another link later on when I find it again.

Finally, using these tools one should be able to get started. Another interesting option is the use of the H264 video codec, and then one needs to port it to .NET himself probably using the [`DllImportAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class. I didn't test anything yet on that direction.

Back in the Classic ASP, an iFrame shall be used to display the content of the streaming using the underlying Silverlight application.

I hope this will help someone someday, as it requires hours and hours of research and readings! =)